# TransactedReceiveScope - when does the Transaction Commit?

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

Scenario:

We have a wcf workflow with a client that does NOT use transactionflow.
The workflow contains several sequential TransactedReceiveScopes (using content-based correlation).
The TransactedReceiveScopes contain custom db operations.

Observations:

When we run SQL profiler against the first call, we see all the custom db calls, and the SaveInstance call in the profile trace.

We've noticed that, even though the SendReply is at the very end of TransactedReceiveScope, sometimes the sendreply occurs a good 10 seconds before the transaction gets committed.

We tried changing the TimeToPersist and TimeToUnload to zero, but that had no effect. (The trace shows the SaveInstance happening immediately anyway, but rather the commit seems to be delayed).

Questions:

Are our observations correct?

At what point is the transaction committed? Is this like garbage collection - i.e. it commits some time later when it's not busy?

Is there any way to control the commit delay, or is the only way to do this to use transactionflow from the client (anc then it should all commit when the client commits, including the persist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TransactedReceiveScope commits the transaction when the body is completed but as all execution is done through the scheduler that could be some time later. It is not related to garbage collection and there is no real way to influence it other that to avoid a busy machine and a lot of other parallel activities that could also be in the execution queue.

Comment: Thanks Maurice. I still find it odd that you see all the SQL calls in profiler including the saveinstance, then it returns to the client, but the there is still a delay after that before it commits. I need to read up on the scheduler, I've not seen much mention of that. The only solution seems to be to use TransactionFlow from the client to control the commit of the transaction, even though the client has no work of it's own to add to the transaction.

Comment: Another point for anyone reading this is that if your client is not flowing a transaction into the workflow, then in most cases you just want a standard receive/sendreply with a transactionscope in between.